# Flattening an association list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

```
(define (associate lst)
    (if (or (null? lst) (= (length lst) 1))
        '()
        (cons (cons (car lst) (cadr lst)) (associate (cddr lst)))))

(define (disassociate lst)
    ;(display (caar lst))
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (cons (caar lst) (cdar lst)) (disassociate (cdr lst)))))

(display (disassociate '((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3))))
(newline)
(display (associate '(a 1 b 2 c)))
(newline)
```

OUTPUT:

```
;; with list
((a 1) ((b 2) ((c 3) ())))
((a . 1) (b . 2))

;; with cons
((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3))
((a . 1) (b . 2))
```

I'm trying to flatten an association list in `Scheme` but the brackets
keep turning up even when I change the `list` to `cons`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an error in the way you're creating the list in `disassociate`. Try this:

```
(define (disassociate lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (caar lst)
            (cons (cdar lst) 
                  (disassociate (cdr lst))))))
```

Or alternatively, using [`list*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%2a%29%29):

```
(define (disassociate lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (list* (caar lst)
             (cdar lst) 
             (disassociate (cdr lst)))))
```

The above assumes that the association list is using `cons` to stick together the values, notice how the output list is created by `cons`ing the first element, then the second and then calling the recursion. On the other hand, if the association list was created using `list` to stick together the values, then this is the way to disassociate it:

```
(define (disassociate lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (caar lst)
            (cons (cadar lst) ; here's the change
                  (disassociate (cdr lst))))))
```

Or alternatively:

```
(define (disassociate lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (list* (caar lst)
             (cadar lst) ; here's the change
             (disassociate (cdr lst)))))
```

A more idiomatic solution would be to use higher-order procedures to process the input list. Here's how, using [`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) for the two association list variants described in the question:

```
; associations created with cons
(define (disassociate lst)
  (foldr (lambda (pr ac) (list* (car pr) (cdr pr) ac))
         '()
         lst))

; associations created with list
(define (disassociate lst)
  (foldr (lambda (pr ac) (list* (car pr) (cadr pr) ac))
         '()
         lst))
```

Comment: That is a lot to chew on. I didn't know `list*` or `foldr` existed till now. Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: @gebby always my pleasure! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `disassociate` line needs to read:

```
(cons (caar lst) (cons (cdar lst) (disassociate (cdr lst)))))
```

**quasi-quotation!** Sometimes these are more clearly implemented using quasi-quotation because quasi-quotation lets you see the resulting list structure.

```
(define (associate lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)))
       '()
       `(,(cons (car lst) (cadr lst)) ,@(associate (cddr lst)))))

(define (disassociate lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      `(,(caar lst) ,(cdar lst) ,@(disassociate (cdr lst)))))

> (associate (disassociate '((a . 1) (b . 2))))
((a . 1) (b . 2))
```

Note that you could also write the `associate` quasi-quotation as:

```
       `((,(car lst) . ,(cadr lst)) ,@(associate (cddr list)))))
```

but that starts getting harder to read for me even though it makes the association pair explicit.

Comment: My imagination is truly lacking. I thought quasi quotation was only useful in writing literal lists. I'm surprised it works.

Comment: quasi-quotation is syntax for: `quasiquote`, `unquote`, `unquote-splicing` and `quote` syntactic keywords.  The syntax transformers convert it directly into `list`, `cons`, etc.  You let the compiler 'optimize' the list creation.

Comment: Also, seeing your other comment, `list*`, `foldr` and `foldr` are not a part of any RnRS Scheme specification (R6RS does have `fold-left` and `fold-right`).  Those functions are probably part of Racket or a SRFI library and easy enough to implement if you care to.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks mate! It's appreciated.